# Python - How to combine ODE with CSV data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to combine a system of differential equations in steady state with data from a CSV that varies with time.

I've managed to figure out how to plot the data separately, it's just getting them both combined that's bugging me (I'm a Python beginner). "A" within the ODE "dC1dt" is the additional data from the CSV in question:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Model
def model(C,t):

    C1 = 400
    C2 = 600
    C3 = 900

    K1 = 3
    K2 = 4
    K3 = 9
    K4 = 10
    #A = 

    dC1dt = (K1 * C2 - K2 * C1) # + A
    dC2dt = (K3 * C3 - K4 * C2) + (K2 * C1 - K1 * C2)
    dC3dt = K4 * C2 - K3 * C3
    return dC1dt + dC2dt + dC3dt

# Initial condition
C0 = 400

# Time points
t = np.linspace(0,3000,num=1000)

# Solve ODE
C = odeint(model,C0,t)

# Plot results
plt.plot(t,C)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Variable')
plt.title('Model')
plt.show()
```

The CSV is just two columns:

Time, Variable

10, 1

20, 3

30, 8

etc.

The data in the CSV increases exponentially with time so the final result should show an increasing trend. Any help would be greatly appreciated!